# Showing one-to-many relationship in Django views

Tags: python, django

I am making a django blog and want to show a list of comments for each blog post, but I have trouble figuring out how to reference the comments in the views and the templates.
My models are defined like this:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    commenter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue)
    text = models.TextField()
```

and my views like this

```
class IssueDetail(DetailView):
    model = Issue
    context_object_name = "issue"
    template_name = "issue_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IssueDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
        return context

class CommentDetail(DetailView):
    model = Comment
    context_object_name = "comment"
    template_name = "comment_detail.html"
```

and finally the issue_detail.html template

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>{{ issue.title }}</h2>
        <br/>
        <i>As written by {{ issue.author.first_name }}</i>
        <br/><br/>
        <blockquote> {{ issue.text }}</blockquote>
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        {% for comment in comments %}
            <li>{{comment}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This allows me to reference the fields of the comment inside the Issue template, but basically then I want the comments to have a template of their own that will be rendered inside the for loop. What is the correct way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `comments` are already available in your template because of the model relationship you defined. You can delete the `get_context_data` in `IssueDetail`.

Your `issue_detail.html` template could look like this:

```
{% for comment in issue.comment_set.all %}
  {% include 'comment_detail.html' %}    
{% endfor %}
```

Your `comment_detail.html` template could look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ comment.issue }}</li>
    <li>{{ comment.text }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I love the ready solutions on stackoverflow, its better than reading documentations for django <3

Answer (score 0):

what if this we were using a different model

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

how would we do the CRUD opertions from the templates an the views.py

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30863645)